# Cannot get/use ControlParameter from GridView in a TemplateField SELECT statement

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple GridView (with an ID of 'GridViewAttribs') which displays some values from a database.

Within my GridViewAttribs I wish to have a (nested?) ListView but for some reason I cannot use the asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridViewAttribs" PropertyName as no results are returned in my (nested) ListView.

If I do NOT use the ControlParameter and hardcode my SELECT statement for the ListView, everything works as expected.

Here's my code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceAttribHeadings" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:customer_support_devConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:customer_support_devConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT equipment_attrib_heading_id, equipment_model_id, equipment_attrib_name FROM equipment_new_attrib_headings WHERE (equipment_model_id = @equipment_model_id) AND (equipment_attrib_heading_deleted = 0) ORDER BY equipment_attrib_name">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="" Name="equipment_model_id" 
            SessionField="EquipmentModelID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="GridViewAttribs" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="equipment_attrib_heading_id" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceAttribHeadings" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
    style="margin-right: 0px">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="equipment_attrib_heading_id" 
            HeaderText="equipment_attrib_heading_id" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="equipment_attrib_heading_id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="equipment_model_id" HeaderText="equipment_model_id" 
            SortExpression="equipment_model_id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="equipment_attrib_name" 
            HeaderText="equipment_attrib_name" SortExpression="equipment_attrib_name" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="equipment_attrib_value_details" SortExpression="equipment_attrib_value_details">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceAttribValues" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:customer_support_devConnectionString %>" 
                    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:customer_support_devConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [equipment_attrib_value_details] FROM [equipment_new_attrib_values] WHERE (equipment_attrib_heading_id = @head_id) AND (equipment_id = @equipment_id) AND (equipment_attrib_value_deleted = 0)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="equipment_id" QueryStringField="id" 
                            Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridViewAttribs" 
                            Name="head_id" PropertyName="SelectedDataKey.Values[equipment_attrib_heading_id]" Type="Int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>

                <asp:ListView ID="ListViewAttribValues" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceAttribValues">
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <table runat="server" style="">
                            <tr><td>No data was returned.</td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr style="">
                            <td><asp:Label ID="equipment_attrib_value_detailsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("equipment_attrib_value_details") %>' /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                            <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

The GridView displays all columns fine except the "equipment_attrib_value_details" column where I get "No data was returned."

However, if I take out the asp:ControlParameter which calls upon @head_id and use this hardcoded SELECT statement then I see the correct (albeit hardcoded) values:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [equipment_attrib_value_details] FROM [equipment_new_attrib_values] WHERE (equipment_attrib_heading_id = 3) AND (equipment_id = @equipment_id) AND (equipment_attrib_value_deleted = 0)">
```

Therefore, for some reason, it would appear that the GridViewAttribs value of "equipment_attrib_heading_id" is not being passed to / picked up by the nested asp:ControlParameter

On the off chance, I've also tried replacing:

```
PropertyName="SelectedDataKey.Values[equipment_attrib_heading_id]"
```

With:

```
PropertyName="SelectedValue"
```

But this didn't resolve the issue either, still not data was returned.

If it helps, I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with ASP.NET4 (vb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could try is using a hidden field and use that control for the controlparameter

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="equipment_attrib_value_details" SortExpression="equipment_attrib_value_details">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="heading_id" Value='<%# Eval("equipment_attrib_heading_id") %>' />
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceAttribValues" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:customer_support_devConnectionString %>" 
                            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:customer_support_devConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT [equipment_attrib_value_details] FROM [equipment_new_attrib_values] WHERE (equipment_attrib_heading_id = @head_id) AND (equipment_id = @equipment_id) AND (equipment_attrib_value_deleted = 0)">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="equipment_id" QueryStringField="id" Type="Int32" />
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="heading_id" Name="head_id" PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>

                        <asp:ListView ID="ListViewAttribValues" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceAttribValues">
                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                <table id="Table2" runat="server" style="">
                                    <tr><td>No data was returned.</td></tr>
                                </table>
                            </EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <tr style="">
                                    <td><asp:Label ID="equipment_attrib_value_detailsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("equipment_attrib_value_details") %>' /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <LayoutTemplate>
                                <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                                    <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                 </LayoutTemplate>
         </asp:ListView>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: GENIUS! Works perfectly! But I don't understand why this works?? Can you shed any further light on what I was doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This only works (it seems) if the `HiddenField` is inside the same `ItemTemplate`. If the `DataSource` is somewhere outside the `TemplateField`, in cases where you want to *data-populate* a control that is say on another column or field of the GridView, then the `HiddenField` will not work, as it's technically **hidden**.

The way to overcome this is in code-behind. Here is how I do it...

I have a `TemplateField` that is referring to @StudentID, which is actually a `HiddenField` in **another TemplateField**.

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Currently&lt;br/&gt;Tracking&lt;br/&gt;(past weeks)">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="listWeeksTracking" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsTETpastWeeks" DataTextField="WeekNo" DataValueField="WeekNo" 
                    OnDataBound="listWeeksTracking_DataBound" OnDataBinding="listWeeksTracking_DataBinding"></asp:CheckBoxList>
                    <br />
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsTETpastWeeks" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ATCNTV1ConnectionString %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT tb.WeekNo, ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 ts.ETRTWtracking FROM tblTETMeetingStudent AS ts INNER JOIN tblTETMeeting AS tm ON tm.TETmeetingID = ts.TETmeetingID AND tm.WeekNo = tb.WeekNo WHERE ts.StudentID = @StudentID),0) AS Tracking FROM tblTETInstructionalTrainingBlocks AS tb WHERE tb.WeekNo <= @WeekNo AND tb.Active = 1 AND tb.YearNum = YEAR(@TETdate) ORDER BY tb.WeekNo">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="StudentID" Type="string" />
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlWeekNo" Name="WeekNo" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="int16" />
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblTETdate" Name="TETdate" Type="DateTime" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

So I define the @StudentID parameter as simple a parameter, and not a `ControlParameter`, is it won't be able to pick up the hiddenfield elsewhere in my GridView.

In code-behind (C#), I trap the Selecting event via the **DataBinding**.
And in there I specifically look for the row in relation to the control I've just populated (or about to), and then I look for the HiddenField.

```
protected void listWeeksTracking_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //set the parameter for the StudentID here as using hiddenfields does not work directly in asp.net, as they are hidden!
    CheckBoxList cbl1 = (CheckBoxList)sender;
    GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)cbl1.NamingContainer;
    if (gvRow != null)
    {
        SqlDataSource sdsTETpastWeeks = (SqlDataSource)gvRow.FindControl("sdsTETpastWeeks");
        HiddenField hfStudentID = (HiddenField)gvRow.FindControl("hfStudentID");
        if (hfStudentID != null) sdsTETpastWeeks.SelectParameters["StudentID"].DefaultValue = hfStudentID.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Voila!